# Adding specific color for defined value on plt.colorbar (matplotlib)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

My code finally generates an image using:

```
plt.imshow(z, extent=(np.amin(x_values), 
                      np.amax(x_values), 
                      np.amin(y_values), 
                      np.amax(y_values)), 
           aspect = "auto", origin = "lower")

plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

The image then looks like this:
[image]

The three colored squares are the actual points of measurement, the rest is just filled with the minimal value of the data. Is there a way, so that I can add a specific color below the colorbar for the "filler-data"? I want it to look more or less like this:
[image: The entire dark blue space then should have the color I specify.]

I hope I can convey what I want to achieve.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If this is about the image, you may mask the data in z or set them to `nan`. You might then manually create a legend with a patch of the color of the axes background.

Comment: Actually, the "nan" already leads to a suitable result. Thank you!